# Is there any way to implement hand gesture detection in flutter using mediapipe?

Tags: flutter, dart, mediapipe

I am trying to build an app in flutter that can detect thumbs up,thumbs down and finger counts.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures

Comment: No I asked about hand gesture detection from camera that can detect thumbs up,thumbs down and finger counts using camera

Comment: check out this project. https://github.com/lcw99/FlutterWithMediaPipe

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it using [OpenCV](https://pub.dev/packages/opencv) instead of MediaPipe. It may need a little bit more of development on your side, but I remember I did a fingers up counter with C++ and OpenCV and it was in a couple of hours.

But if you stick to Flutter + MediaPipe, there is also a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mediapipe). I haven't tried it myself but it states hand tracking (which I am not sure will meet your requirements).